# Firefox 60.0.2 not rendering columns in list correctly

Tags: css, firefox

EDIT: Link to reproduction on codepen
https://codepen.io/bedelman851/pen/oyWpGq

I have a ul to which I am applying `columns: 3` to. Each li has an input/custom label. The custom label has the following relevant css.

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block !important; //ie fix
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 1px solid $dark-button;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: $white;
  left: 0;
  top: 5px;
}
```

The height 16px is still being applied to the element, but is actually getting rendered as over 18px when I inspect the element. All others are exactly 16px. This only seems to happen at the top of the last column.

[image: Refer to last column for issue.]
It doesn't always happen as you'll see in this picture. [image]

But I have noticed that the last column in the second picture sometimes does appear this way. If I go in to the inspector and click on the height to disable it and then reenable it, it renders perfectly. Have tried adding !important (god help us) to the height, and adding a min-height. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Just updated with a codepen link @OrtomalaLokni

Comment: Your css is not valid. Can you validate with https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and update your codepen?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I don't believe that is true. It is SCSS and not plain CSS. I have updated with plain css though for sake of clarity

Answer (score 2):

This was an actual firefox bug that has now been resolved a year later. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1468654